# Transfer fund from stripe's connected account to stripe's platform account

Tags: java, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Is it possible to transfer fund directly from stripe's connected/managed account to stripe's platform account or any other stripe account without using credit/debit card of connected account's owner?

Comment: No. At this time, Stripe allows only for transfers _from_ the platform _to_ a connected account.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Ywain

Answer (score 1):

Stripe is going to provide [Debiting Managed Accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits). Currently it is in beta.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can transfer funds from Stripe platform account to managed account.

But If you want you can transfer some percentage of each charge to platform account directly without any transaction fees.

just use "application_fees" parameter in charge object and that much amount is gone into platform account.

Comment: can you please tell me can i transfer funds from Stripe platform account to stripe standalone account.